# Can I replace "to conquer" by "conquering" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

The green, the result of men’s toil **to conquer** nature, is wheat fields blown by the breeze into green waves.

Comment: Not really. (It's possible, but a little awkward: it reads like *their toil-conquering nature*.) However, you could replace *to conquer* with *in conquering* …

Comment: @KikiMomo What are you trying to express that you think the infinitive form doesn’t convey?

Comment: I was just wondering if it is right grammarly. Many thanks!!

Comment: Where is this sentence from, please? I'm having trouble trying to decide whether I'd dock a mark for non-idiomaticity if marking an essay. // Certainly, _Their toil conquering nature_ sounds unnatural, whether or not it's grammatical (it probably is, comparing with ' his work [in] combatting phobias').

Comment: "to conquer" could be "to" + bare infinitive, which is used to express a goal or purpose.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [source](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/gerund-vs-infinitive-practice):

> Gerunds are often used when actions are *real, fixed, or completed*. "I
> enjoy **cooking**." (emphasis added)
>
> Infinitives are often used when actions are *unreal, abstract, or
> future*: "He wants **to swim**." (emphasis added)

I would say the notion of conquering is an abstract action, so the infinitive would be the correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

The gerund and the infinite equate to the continuous and simple forms of the verb.

All simple forms of the verb indicate an action as a whole - from start to finish.

**The simple form of the verb can indicate a habitual or regular action that**

**(i) is/was/will be complete/completed each time it is undertaken.**

A: What do you do to keep fit?

B: I ride a bike. -> “ride” includes everything from getting on the bike at the start of the journey to getting off the bike at the end.

Or

**(ii) a single, complete or completed present, future, or past action:**

"He told me that I had to visit the Eiffel Tower, so I go/went/will go to Paris on Wednesday” -> “go/went/will go” includes everything from the decision being made, bags being packed, going to the airport, etc., to the arrival in Paris.

**(iii) a habitual, recurring, regular or frequent action (that is completed each time)**

On Saturdays, I go to the gym.

He ate toast for breakfast every day of his life.

**The continuous form of the verb indicates**

(i) an action that is/was/will be (a) incomplete and (b) in progress **and** (c) at the time that is being referred to (it has started but it has not yet finished) ->

I will be/am/was/have been/had been riding a bike = I will be/am/was/have been/had been in the process of riding a bike but have not yet finished riding the bike at the time I am referring to.

The continuous form used to be known as “the imperfect”: It was called “imperfect” because the action had not been “perfected” i.e. it had not finished.

OED

> Imperfect: 5. Grammar. Applied to a tense which denotes action going on but not completed; usually [edit Q- but not always] to the past tense of incomplete or progressive action.

> 1871 H. J. Roby Gram. Latin Lang. §549 *Three [tenses] denoting incomplete action; the Present, Future, and Imperfect (sometimes called respectively, present imperfect, future imperfect, past imperfect).*

Comment: As usual, distict classification is impossible. _I advised seeing a doctor._ = _I advised them to see a doctor._  //  _I can’t bear hearing him cry._ = _I can’t bear to hear him cry._ // _It began raining._ = _It began to rain._